# Spring.NET - How to choose the implementation of an interface at runtime?

Tags: interface, runtime, spring.net

In all of the examples of Spring.NET IoC, I see something like this:

```
 interface IClass;

 class ClassA : IClass;

 class ClassB : IClass,
```

And then in the config.xml file, something like:

```
[object id="IClass" type="ClassB, Spring.Net.Test" /]
```

But I really need to do something like this in the config file where there will be multiple implementations if interface:

```
[object id="IClass" type="ClassA, Blah" /]

[object id="IClass" type="ClassB, Blah" /]
```

And then in `_runtime_` I choose from them. Something like this:

```
IClass c = [get me all implementations of IClass, and choose the one with 
            GetType().FullName == myVariableContainingFullTypeNameOfObjectIWant]
```

How can I do something like this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar before and took an approach very similar to the one Fabiano has suggested.

Sample config:

<object id="ClassAInstance" type="ClassA, Blah"> ... </object>

<object id="ClassBInstance" type="ClassB, Blah"> ... </object>

Now some generalized sample code using the WebApplicationContext:

```
        IApplicationContext context = new XmlApplicationContext(locations);
        IClass c = (IClass)context.GetObject(declarationId);
```

There are a couple of things to note:

1. Pass in the *id* of the declaration you wish to use not the *Type name*, so the variable **declarationId** would have the value of either "ClassAInstance" or "ClassBInstance".
2. The constructor to XmlApplicationContext (and WebApplicationContext) takes a parameter of an array of string values; the variable **locations** would be an array of configuration resources to search through to find the object with id **declarationId**. You cannot use a generic List here, it has to be an actual string array.

One interesting implication of point 2 above is that you actually control which configuration resources your ApplicationContext is aware of: when you call the GetObject() method, the ApplicationContext will only search for your object within the configuration resources given in the array **locations[]**. This means that rather than list all possible configurations within one file each with a unique id, you can have multiple configuration resources instead, each containing one object declaration and each with the same id:

Config1.xml: <object id="IClassInstance" type="ClassA, Blah"> ... </object>

Config2.xml: <object id="IClassInstance" type="ClassA, Blah"> ... </object>

But when instantiating the object, you can control which object is created not based on the **declarationId**, which in both cases will be "IClassInstance", but by changing the **locations[]** array to contain the configuration resource you want to use, in this case either Config1.xml or Config2.xml

Hope this is of use,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try this:

[object id="Blah.ClassA" type="ClassA, Blah" /]

[object id="Blah.ClassB" type="ClassB, Blah" /]

IClass = (IClass) ApplicationContext.GetObject(myVariableContainingFullTypeNameOfObjectIWant);